# Get only defined attributes of object in Python

Tags: python-3.x, class, object, attributes, python-dataclasses

I want to get all the attributes of an object in Python I have defined myself to create a string representation. I want to prevent writing it by hand and filling in all the variables myself, so adding/removing attributes in the future does not amount to mistakes.

For example, in the code below I am looking for a way to retrieve all the attributes I have defined myself: email, password and birthday.

Is there a way to do this in Python?

```
class Account:
    def __init__(self, email, password, birthday):
        self.email = email
        self.password = password
        self.birthday = birthday

    def __str__(self):
        delim = ","
        # I want to prevent writing this all out
        return f"{self.email}{delim}{self.password}{delim}{self.birthday}"


print(Account("manfred@gmail.com", "hunter2", 3))
```

Comment: In this case, just use `self.__dict__` or equivalently, `vars(self)`, both return the object's namespace, which is a `dict` mapping attribute names to attribute values

Answer (score 0):

You could use a list comprehension:
You need to define an instance of your class:

```
A = Account("manfred@gmail.com", "hunter2", 3)
{i:getattr(A, i) for i in dir(A) if not i.startswith("_")}

{'birthday': 3, 'email': 'manfred@gmail.com', 'password': 'hunter2'}
```

Comment: `for i in dir(A)` *no no no*. Don't do that. Use `vars(A)` or `A.__dict__`. `dir` is not meant for this

Answer (score 0):

Try something like this

```py
list(Account("manfred@gmail.com", "hunter2", 3).__dict__.values())
```